# Exclude records from a SQL SUM based on a flag field

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using daily clock-in data to calculate Overtime Hours worked at a daily and week-to-date level. However, if someone's timecard entry for a day is based on a vacation/personal time off, those hours should not count toward *overtime* for the week. These specific records are marked with a 'PTO_FLAG' field = 1 when this is applies.

I cannot figure out what the logic needs to be to to make this happen.

This is what I have so far and it returns accurate totals, but I need to include the wrinkle about excluding WHEN PTO_FLAG = 1

```
SUM ( HOURS ) 
        OVER 
        ( PARTITION BY 
            YRWKINDEX, EMPLOYEE_ID 
            ORDER BY WORK_DATE asc
        ) 
    AS WK_TO_DATE_HOURS,
CASE
    WHEN WK_TO_DATE_HOURS > 40 THEN WK_TO_DATE_HOURS - 40
    ELSE 0
END 
    AS WTD_OVERTIME_HOURS,
CASE
    WHEN ( WK_TO_DATE_HOURS - 40 ) < 0 
    THEN 0 
    WHEN ( WK_TO_DATE_HOURS - 40 ) < HOURS
    THEN WK_TO_DATE_HOURS - 40
    WHEN ( WK_TO_DATE_HOURS - 40 ) > 0
    AND ( WK_TO_DATE_HOURS - 40 ) > HOURS
    THEN HOURS
END
    AS OVERTIME_HOURS
```

[image of current query results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFJiT.png)

Comment: You should search for `conditional aggregation`. Your question is missing both sample data and expected results. So it's hard to say what query exactly would be correct. You likely need something like `SUM(CASE PTO_FLAG WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE hours END)...`

Comment: By the way, your current query is quite bad to read due to those strange `CASE` constructs. They can be removed and replaced by `GREATEST` which is mush shorter and easier to read. For example `GREATEST(WK_TO_DATE_HOURS - 40, 0)` rather than `CASE WHEN WK_TO_DATE_HOURS > 40 THEN WK_TO_DATE_HOURS - 40 ELSE 0 END `

Comment: Also, please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: @NickW thanks for letting me know. First time posting here and didn't see how to paste the image straight in. Will enter results as text next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so CASE or the tidier IFF can be used inside the SUM thus:

```
sum(iff(PTO_FLAG = 1, null, HOURS )) 
   OVER ( PARTITION BY YRWKINDEX, EMPLOYEE_ID ORDER BY WORK_DATE asc ) 
   AS WK_TO_DATE_HOURS,
```

should do the trick.

as per Jonas comment the formula for `WTD_OVERTIME_HOURS`:

```
CASE
    WHEN WK_TO_DATE_HOURS > 40 THEN WK_TO_DATE_HOURS - 40
    ELSE 0
END as WTD_OVERTIME_HOURS
```

could be replaced with a IFF:

```
iff(WK_TO_DATE_HOURS > 40, WK_TO_DATE_HOURS - 40, 0) as WTD_OVERTIME_HOURS
```

or with an greatest:

```
greatest( WK_TO_DATE_HOURS - 40, 0) as WTD_OVERTIME_HOURS
```

I normally would go with IFF, but the greatest reads cleaner. The next thing to  learn is Snowflake is you can reuse the prior results so `OVERTIME_HOURS` is really the greatest of `HOURS` and `WTD_OVERTIME_HOURS`

thus the SQL could be written:

```
sum(iff(PTO_FLAG = 1, null, HOURS )) 
    OVER ( PARTITION BY YRWKINDEX, EMPLOYEE_ID ORDER BY WORK_DATE asc )
    AS WK_TO_DATE_HOURS,
greatest( WK_TO_DATE_HOURS - 40, 0) as WTD_OVERTIME_HOURS,
greatest( WTD_OVERTIME_HOURS, HOURS ) as OVERTIME_HOURS
```